# Antdesign table not rerendering on new column values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, antd

I am having trouble rerendering the columns of my table, the library i am using is ant design and I am trying to create a feature where I reorder the column of the table on demand.

I have created an example the issue here: https://replit.com/@coupacoupa/Ant-Design-column-reordering

In the example, I created a simple button that changes the order of the column which changes  a div showcasing the state changed, but in the ant design table, the column doesn't change.

Below  is a snipplet of the way I change the state

```html
export default ({ columnOrder, data }: IProps) => {
  const [orderedColumn, setOrderedColumn] = useState<ColumnsType<ISomeTableColumns>>(columns);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('columnOrder', columnOrder);
    const sortArray = columns.sort((a, b) => {
      return (
        columnOrder.findIndex((x) => x.text === a.title) -
        columnOrder.findIndex((x) => x.text === b.title)
      );
    });

    if (sortArray) {
      setOrderedColumn(sortArray);
    }
  }, [columnOrder]);

  return <>
    <Table
      columns={orderedColumn}
      dataSource={data}
      bordered
      size="middle"
      scroll={{ x: 'calc(700px + 50%)' }}
    />
    <h2>Value Of ordered Columns</h2>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(orderedColumn)}</div>
  </>
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sort() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the reference to the same array, now sorted. But you should pass a new array into setOrderedColumn to rerender

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('columnOrder', columnOrder);
    columns.sort((a, b) => {
      return (
        columnOrder.findIndex((x) => x.text === a.title) -
        columnOrder.findIndex((x) => x.text === b.title)
      );
    });

    if (columns) {
      setOrderedColumn([...columns]);
    }
  }, [columnOrder, columns]);
```

Comment: thanks for the short and clear explanation!